# How to enable any language other than Python?

Tags: go, ide, nim-lang, liclipse

I recently found out about liclipse and was very excited about its concept (lite eclipse) especially when newly installed Liclipse managed to start up in 5 seconds. But it seems I cannot find how to use it for any of languages listed on the website as it comes only with PyDev perspective and several other Python-related things (e.g. PyDev), but since I am not a Python developer and was looking for nim and Go support I started exploring their documentation but had no success.

So my question is if I should install the plugins for languages I want (e.g. like in standard Eclipse) but that would be odd since Liclipse says it supports those languages out-of-the-box.

I downloaded the latest version of Liclipse from their website and am on Win32 p;latform if it changes anything.

Comment: Does it not syntax highlight Nim or Go code? Or are you looking for other features (eg. code completion)?

Answer (score 0):

LiClipse has a lightweight editor for those languages (which provides basic syntax highlighting, outline, comment/uncomment and basic code-completion -- i.e.: based on templates), so, if that's enough for you, you should be able to just open the file you want and use the provided editor.

Now, if you require more features for some given language, you can still install another more full-featured plugin to edit it.

Related to the perspective, you should be able to use the Resource Perspective for any language.